# How to update the "total price" column value on change of other column "qty" value in datagrid for each row in GWT?

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` table with 5 columns something like below:

```
   |         |            |              qty | 
id | desc    | price/unit | (editable field) | total price
---+---------+------------+------------------+------------
 1 | my id 1 |         10 |                1 |         10
 2 | my id 2 |         20 |                2 |         40
 3 | my id 3 |         30 |                3 |         90
 4 | my id 4 |         40 |                4 |        160
```

My need here is if I am updating the `qty` value for row 1 from 1 to 10 then it should update the `total price` to 100 for row 1. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the [FieldUpdater](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/FieldUpdater.html) of your editable column you have the `update` method. This method gets `rowIndex` in its first parameter. This is the row that you need to redraw to refresh the `total price` column. Of course, I assume that `totatl price` is calculated based on current `qty` and `price` value.

Like this:

```
qtyColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<RowType, String>() {
    @Override
    public void update(int index, RowType object, String value) {

        ...

        object.setQty(newValue);
        grid.redrawRow(index);
    }
});
```